# How can I call a JS function in one HTML file who's input was entered in another HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the first time I'm asking a question on stackoverflow (before I was just reading) and I'm super new to coding in general, so please be patient with me.

I'm trying to build my first simple PWA. It stores data only locally, so no backend integration necessary. I still want to give the user the impression of having an account however. For that reason, I have created two .html sites at the moment. One is the main page (`index.html`) where the content lives and the second is called settings (`settings.html`) and it holds a text field where you can input your name. On the first page, it will then greet you (Hello Name). It works, but only if I include the function on `index.html` (where the fake settings menu wouldn't make sense).

Here is the code:

First page **`index.html`**:

```html
<body onload="userName()">
    <div class="Top">
      <h3>Hello <span id="Name"></span></h3>
      <a href="Settings.html">
        <button>Settings</button>
      </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

**`script.js`**:

```js
function userName() {
  let text = Name.value;
  document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = text;
}
```

This is the function I have to include in `<body></body>` on `index.html` as well for it to work, but I would like to have in on my "fake settings" page **`settings.html`**:

```html
<h3>Your name</h3>
<input id="Name" value="Dummy" type="text" />
```

If anyone has an idea I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Thats not how web applications work. Beside that, a button within an ancjor is invalid. You can not nest an interactive element inside another. HTML works by so called Requests. It requesting resources from a server such as a HTML file. For obviouse security reasons it has not the ability to recieve anything without requesting it

Comment: @tacoshy I disagree with you, you can have a web app that is purely frontend. Beside, HTML has little to do with requests, that's a markup language. You probably meant HTTP

Comment: If you want to save some variables between 2 pages, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to set and get values

Answer (score -1):

Add your js in a separate file. And then include that file before closing the body tag in both html files. just like this:
index.html

```
<body>
 <div class="Top">
      <h3>Hello <span id="Name"></span></h3>
      <a href="Settings.html">
        <button>Settings</button>
      </a>
    </div>

    <script src="path of your file/ main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Setting.html

```
 <body>
 <h3>Your name</h3>
    <input id="Name" value="Dummy" type="text" />
<script src="path of your file/ main.js"></script>
    </body>
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything to pass data between pages, you just end up with two different instances of that JS file, one on each page.